# how can i show word doc or pdf in flash paper?

Tags: flash

Hello I am new in Flash related application. i need to convert word or html file to PDF and show that pdf file as flashpaper [the PDF file should not be editable and downloadable]. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you actually have to convert the file to flashpaper in order to do anything with it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashPaper